# How is it possible to include appendix sections in TOC (beamer)?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, appendices

I need to add section of appendix to main TOC:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}{Main}
            Main
        \end{frame}

        \section{First}
        \begin{frame}{First}
            First
        \end{frame}

        \section{Second}
        \begin{frame}{Second}
            Second
        \end{frame}

        \section*{Content}
        \label{sec:main-content}
        \begin{frame}{Content}
            \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
        \end{frame}

        \appendix

        \section{First-Appendix}
        \begin{frame}{First-Appendix}
            Second
        \end{frame}     
    \end{document}
```

This code does not work...

Comment: Do you want to show the appendix sections *only* in the ToC or also in an eventual navigation bar?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'd like to add only to ToC. I need as more simple as it could be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `beamer`, the `\part` subdivisions are treated as completely separate entities with their own table of contents.  What `\appendix` does is start a new `\part`.  So firstly, a `\tableofcontents` after `\appendix` gives a list of the `\sections` etc. in the `\appendix` only.  A demonstration of this is included in the `beamer` documentation.

One simple way to get the `\tableofcontents` in a main document, which does not have any `\part` divisions, to include entries from the `\appendix` is to reset the `part` counter after starting the `\appendix`:

```
\appendix\addtocounter{part}{-1}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Main}
    Main
\end{frame}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}{First}
    First
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}{Second}
    Second
\end{frame}

\section*{Content}
\label{sec:main-content}
\begin{frame}{Content}
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\appendix\addtocounter{part}{-1}
\section{First-Appendix}

\begin{frame}{First-Appendix}
    Second
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```